# What are the numbers that appear in Microsoft Visual Studio Source Control after branches

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, if you are using Source control (in my case with BitBucket), the branches display followed by a number.  It looks like a MAC address but I can't confirm that.  It is not my serial number.  What is that number?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

Those are the beginning of the [hashes of those commits.](https://www.ralfebert.de/git/historie/)

Comment: thanks by the way!  Is there any good usage for that information?  It seems useful at least as a way to make sure you have the right commit, assuming you can see that hash in the repository.

Comment: Yes that and whenever you need to reference a commit, like with `git diff`